# Syntax for Win32::GUI::AcceleratorTable

Tags: perl

I want my GUI to react on single key strokes.

This works fine with the -keydown option as long as the windows object has the focus.

To get feedback about keystrokes without the focus I want to use Win32::GUI::AcceleratorTable.

In the docs I took the code snippets you can see in my code. But I'm confused about the syntax to use. Once the docs say Win32::GUI::Accelerator and in others there is mentioned Win32::AcceleratorTable (even though there is no such package on CPAN). The same with the options -accel, -accelerators and -acceleratortable.

How has the code to look like to get feedback about keycode of a keystroke?

Here is my (not working) code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::GUI();

# define main window
my $window = Win32::GUI::Window->new(
    -name   => 'MainWindow',
    -width  => 250,
    -height => 200,
    -text   => 'keys',
    -accel  => Win32::GUI::AcceleratorTable,    # ????
    # or -accelerator, or -acceleratortable     # ????
);

$window->AddLabel( -name => 'lblStatus', -top => 5, -left => 5, -text => "pressed key", );

# a text field to give feedback about the key press
$window->AddTextfield( -name => 'txtStatus',
    -width => 80,
    -height => 20,
    -top => 20,
    -left => 5,
    -tip => "displays value of key",
);

# I took this from CPAN Win32::GUI::AcceleratorTable which should at least print
# "Hello" on the console if one presses the lowercase letter "b" on the keyboard
$A = Win32::GUI::AcceleratorTable->new(
        "Ctrl-X"       => "Close",
        "Shift-N"      => "New",
        "Ctrl-Alt-Del" => "Reboot",
        "b"      => sub { print "Hello\n"; },
);

# display app
$window->Show();

# start of event handler
Win32::GUI::Dialog();

exit (0);
```

Comment: At the very least, needs to be `-accel => $A`, which also means you'll need to move the initialization of `$A`. (`-accel`, `-accelerator` and `-accelerratortable` are aliases.)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code according to ikegami's hint which solved my problem. Thank you ikegami!

```
# first initialize AcceleratorTable...
my $A = new Win32::GUI::AcceleratorTable(
        "Ctrl-X"       => "Close",
        "Shift-N"      => "New",
        "Ctrl-Alt-Del" => "Reboot",
        "b"      => sub { print "Hello\n"; },
);

# ...and then define main window using the -accel option
my $window = Win32::GUI::Window->new(
    -name   => 'MainWindow',
    -width  => 250,
    -height => 200,
    -text   => 'keys',
    -accel  => $A,
);
```

...and voilà - it works :-)